# iterate over newline-separated list

Tags: lists, line-breaking, loops

For my purposes, it is convenient to have a list given with one element on each line (separated with ASCII `\n`). I want to iterate over such a list. Something like this:

```
\begin{itemize}

\foreachperline{
foo
   bar, baz
abcdef \emph{test}
}{\item TEST#1END}

\end{itemize}
```

This would produce:

- TESTfooEND
- TEST bar, bazEND
- TESTabcdef *test*END

I would prefer for `\foreachperline` to work exactly as above, with the first and last newlines ignored, bit if that's going to get messy, the following would also be okay

```
\foreachperline{foo
   bar, baz
abcdef \emph{test}}{\item TEST#1END}
```

It would also be acceptable (preferable to option 2 but not preferable to option 1) to explicitly mark the ends of lines, something like this

```
\foreachperline{
foo\\
   bar, baz\\
abcdef \emph{test}\\
}{\item TEST#1END}
```

Note that there are no spaces in `TEST#1END` but spaces are in the output according to the contents of the lines (see the `bar` line).

It is not essential to use `#1` as a placeholder. Something like this would also be okay.

```
\foreachperline{
foo
bar, baz
abcdef \emph{test}
}{\item TEST\placeholder{}END}
```

It is not essential for the syntax to be a single macro. Something like this would also be okay.

```
\forthingy \i \in {...}{\item TEST\i{}END}
```

How do I write `\foreachperline`, or something functionally equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

You’re going to shoot your own foot using newlines as delimiters: most editors have their own ideas about how to organize users’ input.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\foreachperline}{m}
 {
  \cs_set_protected:Nn \__spraff_per_line_do:n { #1 }
  \group_begin:
  \char_set_catcode_other:n { 13 }
  \char_set_catcode_active:n { 32 }
  \char_set_active_eq:nN { 32 } \c_space_token
  \__spraff_per_line_go:n
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__spraff_per_line_go:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nfn \l__spraff_per_line_input_seq { \char_generate:nn { 13 } { 12 } } { #1 }
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l__spraff_per_line_input_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l__spraff_per_line_input_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \seq_map_function:NN \l__spraff_per_line_input_seq \__spraff_per_line_do:n
  \group_end:
 }

\seq_new:N \l__spraff_per_line_input_seq
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { Nf }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}

\foreachperline{\item TEST#1END}{
foo
   bar, baz
abcdef \emph{test}
}

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

No compression of the three spaces to one? Well, you know that TeX ignores spaces at the beginning of lines, so either you don't get them or the can't be treated as usual.

Oh, don't even try to feed this as the argument to another command; in particular, no nesting.